# How to override method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I`m trying override "public function sendCode()" to use it in LoginController from below TokenModel.

have done more than tripled confirmed that loading and calling TokenModel from LoginController as an instance is succeed but "public function sendCode()" is not included with TokenModel.

would be very helpful if anyone knows what happens here and tell me what I should code.

=======================TokenModel=========================

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Token extends Model
{
    const EXPIRATION_TIME = 15; // minutes
    protected $fillable = [
        'code',
        'user_id',
        'used'
    ];
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        if (! isset($attributes['code'])) {
            $attributes['code'] = $this->generateCode();
        }
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
    /**
     * Generate a six digits code
     *
     * @param int $codeLength
     * @return string
     */
    public function generateCode($codeLength = 4)
    {
        $min = pow(10, $codeLength);
        $max = $min * 10 - 1;
        $code = mt_rand($min, $max);
        return $code;
    }
    /**
     * User tokens relation
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    /**
     * Send code to user
     *
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function sendCode()
    {
        if (! $this->user) {
            throw new \Exception("No user attached to this token.");
        }
        if (! $this->code) {
            $this->code = $this->generateCode();
        }
        try {
            app('twilio')->messages->create($this->user->getPhoneNumber(),
                ['from' => env('TWILIO_NUMBER'), 'body' => "Your verification code is {$this->code}"]);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return false; //enable to send SMS
        }
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * True if the token is not used nor expired
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isValid()
    {
        return ! $this->isUsed() && ! $this->isExpired();
    }
    /**
     * Is the current token used
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isUsed()
    {
        return $this->used;
    }
    /**
     * Is the current token expired
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isExpired()
    {
        return $this->created_at->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now()) > static::EXPIRATION_TIME;
    }
}
```

=======================LoginController=========================

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Token;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
    /**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);
        //retrieveByCredentials
        if ($user = app('auth')->getProvider()->retrieveByCredentials($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            $token = Token::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id
            ]);
            if ($token->sendCode()) {
                session()->set("token_id", $token->id);
                session()->set("user_id", $user->id);
                session()->set("remember", $request->get('remember'));
                return redirect("code");
            }
            $token->delete();// delete token because it can't be sent
            return redirect('/login')->withErrors([
                "Unable to send verification code"
            ]);
        }
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInputs()
            ->withErrors([
                $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
            ]);
    }
    /**
     * Show second factor form
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showCodeForm()
    {
        if (! session()->has("token_id")) {
            return redirect("login");
        }
        return view("auth.code");
    }
    /**
     * Store and verify user second factor.
     */
    public function storeCodeForm(Request $request)
    {
        // throttle for too many attempts
        if (! session()->has("token_id", "user_id")) {
            return redirect("login");
        }
        $token = Token::find(session()->get("token_id"));
        if (! $token ||
            ! $token->isValid() ||
            $request->code !== $token->code ||
            (int)session()->get("user_id") !== $token->user->id
        ) {
            return redirect("code")->withErrors(["Invalid token"]);
        }
        $token->used = true;
        $token->save();
        $this->guard()->login($token->user, session()->get('remember', false));
        session()->forget('token_id', 'user_id', 'remember');
        return redirect('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by *is not included with TokenModel*? Does your `Token::create` returns instance of `Token` or instance of `Model`/ not `Token`? If `Model`, then you need to also overwrite `create` method in `Token`

Comment: What I means is that when TokenModel gets override, what I`m understanding is method "public function sendCode()" is being able to use in LoginController right?

wired thing here is, method "public function user()" is being able to use in LoginController after override but method sendCode....

Comment: Does your `if ($token->sendCode()) {` throws error that method not found or it simply evaluates to `false`? And you don't need to overwrite method if you do not change anything.

Comment: and Yes, Token::create returns instance of Token Model that is not included sendCode() method.

Comment: What do you mean by "trying override public function"? Where's the code for that?

Comment: ① In LoginController  `use App\Token;`  ② InLoginController  `if ($token->sendCode()) {
                session()->set("token_id", $token->id);
                session()->set("user_id", $user->id);
                session()->set("remember", $request->get('remember'));
                return redirect("code");
            }`